# I would like to create a batch script to run an already made bat script, delay for a few seconds and then type some commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Need some help with this one (I'm new to batch scripting). So here's the problem:

I have a batch file called connection.bat:
   - it connects to a network WiiU console, but it takes a few seconds to load the environment
   - after it loads, it looks something like this:
     @userid:
   - that's when you can type some specific console commands (install and run mostly)

I want to make a batch file that does the following:
1. runs connection.bat
2. waits for it to finish loading the environment
3. and then type the install command

I tried doing it this way:

`cd C:\test\connection.bat install -1 10.xx.xx.xx testupload.pkg`

but it doesn't work, because it needs to connect first to the console

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: PS: I have not made the <b>connection.bat</b> file. It is a standard batch used at my work to connect to the WiiU console, so I cannot give you any details regarding the script used for it.

Comment: Also, the reason I need this specific batch file is because I'm developing a C# WinForms app that simplifies this operation (changing the IP address in the command, or the name of the .pkg file). Maybe there's a way to bypass with C#

Comment: What do you mean the batch file is written with C#? You understand that batch files are executed through the Windows command interpreter.

Comment: I'm using C# StreamWriter to create the batch file, that has the script to run connection.bat, wait 5 second to load the environment and type the install command

Comment: Though, I think I found a method in C# to not create an intermediary batch file. PassMessage to an active cmd window

Answer (score 0):

I always use ping to add a delay in batch files:

```
ping 0.0.0.0 > nul
```

adds a 3 second delay